# Why Python string formatting looks different?

Tags: python, string, format

Why does the Python 3 string formatting look so different between these two code blocks? I would think they should look the same. I would think the results would look the same.

```
def print_formatted(number):
    width_bin = format(number,'b')
    for i in range(1,number+1):

        bi=format(i,'b')
        oc=format(i,'o')
        he=format(i,'X')

        print("{0:{4}} {1:{4}} {2:{4}} {3:{4}}".format(i,oc,he,bi,len(width_bin)))
    return

n = 5
print_formatted(n)
```

Result:

```
  1 1   1   1  
  2 2   2   10 
  3 3   3   11 
  4 4   4   100
  5 5   5   101
```

Versus:

```
def print_formatted(number):
    width_bin = format(number,'b')
    for i in range(1,number+1):

        print("{0:{1}d} {0:{1}o} {0:{1}X} {0:{1}b}".format(i,len(width_bin)))
    return

n = 5
print_formatted(n)
```

Result:

```
  1   1   1   1
  2   2   2  10
  3   3   3  11
  4   4   4 100
  5   5   5 101
```

It seems the right/left justification changes but I don't understand why that is the case.

Comment: In one case you're printing strings, in the other case numbers.  Default justification is different for them.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks! At what point does the number become a string? Does it have to do with storing and passing it to the print statement as a variable?

Comment: Your `bi`, `oc` and `he` are strings because you used `format` to create them.

Comment: But format is used in the second example as well.

Comment: Ah.. I think I understand now. I believe it has to do with when the width subcomponent is applied. In the first case, it applies the width to the string whereas in the second case, width is applied to the integer and then creates the string.